# Spread arbitrary number of divs evenly in a div's rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to achieve an even distribution of pills inside a div for all 4 major screen sizes using flexbox. The smaller the screen size less divs are to be fit to a single row. The rest of the divs should be placed on the next row. The number of divs to distribute is not known beforehand. Each pill is going to receive a word inside so a min guaranteed width is needed.
Here's a picture of what the outcome for various screen sizes might look like for a single row. How do I go about doing smth like this?
[image]

Comment: Please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.pill {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.pill:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
  <div class="pill">bar</div>
  <div class="pill">foobar</div>
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
  <div class="pill">bar</div>
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
  <div class="pill">bar</div>
  <div class="pill">foobar</div>
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
  <div class="pill">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
  <div class="pill">bar</div>
  <div class="pill">foobar</div>
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
  <div class="pill">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
  <div class="pill">bar</div>
  <div class="pill">foobar</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="pill">foo</div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the min and max width of the pill elements according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Imagine I have 14 divs for the desktop screen size. If I set a `min-width` to a pill div so there only 6 pill divs fit to a row will the remaining pill divs go to the next row?

Comment: Yes. I added a case like that to the example.